# Permission Error when trying to import SQL

Tags: permissions, import

On an attempt to import an SQL into a Database I get this error.

```
* Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task 1: Executing the query "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name..." failed with the following error: "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'WebsiteDatabase'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. We appreciate your participation. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question is very open ended and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) or [**too broad**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). Consider [adding](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/238634/edit) more information: e.g. how are you importing the data, what tools are you using, GUI, which RDBMS is affected,..

Answer (score 1):

That error is fairly straightforward, the Import Wizard is checking if the destination table exists and trying to create it because it is missing, but your login doesn't have sufficient permissions on the database or server to create a table.

I'm assuming you're not a DBA based on the question, so you're probably best placed to have your DBA look at either creating the table for you, running the import for you or granting you the required permissions.